# How to create a webservice for Ipad in .Net which returns JSON?

Tags: .net, json, web-services, ipad

I want to create a webservice which can be used in Ipad takes argument through coding from the app in Ipad and returns a JSON. The webservice should be in .NET. Can please anyone help me?

```
     JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

      return js.Serialize("Abc");
```

Not returning a value. When we use Get Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the service to run on an iPad, or be accessible from an iPad?  If the former, then I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  If the latter, then it really has nothing to do with an iPad.

In .NET there are a number of ways to create a service which returns JSON.  Keep in mind in this regard that "web service" doesn't have to mean WCF or SOAP or anything like that.  It's just a resource on the web.  For example, if you have an MVC site then you can simply return string content from your controller and use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to serialize your objects to JSON.

From the perspective of the consuming client it doesn't really care how the JSON is created on the server, it just needs a JSON-parsable string.  Something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return Content(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("testing"));
}
```

Here I'm just serializing the string "testing" but you can pass any object to the `Serialize()` method (provided that it's serializable).

Comment: Be accessible from Ipad. So that i can use it for coding

Comment: @Aditi: Then it's no different from any other web resource.  You'll have to have a place to host it, of course.  I imagine you could do development locally with a local web service, but once the app is live it'll need to access a server somewhere.  Either way, the platform of the consuming client doesn't affect the service itself.

Comment: I want to make webservice which will be returning an JSON array and will be used while developing a IPad application.

Comment: @Aditi: Right.  It can be used by anything, that's my point.  The "iPad" part is immaterial to creating the service.  Now, are you having trouble creating the service?  Is it not working in the way that you expect?  As you narrow in on a specific issue you can edit your question to reflect that (include code, errors, etc.).

Comment: I have edit the post. Not getting a return value. While I am using get method

Comment: @Aditi: What is it returning?  The code specified in the question doesn't have any surrounding context, so I don't know if it's in an MVC action or a WebForm page load or a WCF service, etc.  But when you debug the client you should be able to see what is being returned.  If it's an error, it probably has useful information about what caused it.

Comment: Have sorted the issue. but still it is returning Xml tag above the result. Do you have any idea how can we remove xml tags?